# Using Atheros® 802.11b/g wireless with Ubuntu 12.10, connecting but not downloading pages

Tags: wireless

I get a clear signal and the computer shows that it is connected to the network, but the pages don't load.  The message at the bottom of the window reads: "waiting for www.google.com..." -or- whatever page I am trying to get. Also, with this WiFi device, will I be able to stream live TV?  Or should I purchase a newer WiFi USB device?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're connecting fine to your WiFi router. So, if possible, try to access your router configuration page (you will find details on how to do this in your router handbook) and check if you have in place restrictions like MAC filtering or some firewall settings for your connection.

Comment: I don't do formatting.  I am a grandma for goodness sake.  So I hope this comment will work without mini-Markdown formatting, whatever that is.  I have two other MacBooks that are using the wireless network just fine.  Is the problem because the Atheros is a 802.11b/g without the n device?  The router is a Linksys E4200 which is 802.11b/g/n technology.  I called Cisco and they offered to sell me a bridge adapter to get this to work.  $71.  Is that necessary?  I don't want to spend the extra cash.